# jquery - ajax request is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, jquery-ui, jquery-autocomplete

I'm using jQuery autocomplete http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#remote-jsonp where the ajax request is not working (not sending request to the specified url)

Here is the jQuery code:

```
$("#add-keywords").autocomplete({
    source: function( request, response ) {
        var q = $("#add-keywords").val();
        $.ajax({
            url: "/keywords_suggestions/",
            dataType: "json",
            data: {
                    query: q
            }
        });
    },
    minLength: 2,
    select: function( event, ui ) {
            log( ui.item ?
                "Selected: " + ui.item.label :
                "Nothing selected, input was " + this.value);
    }
});
```

The requesting url should be this `http://127.0.0.1:8000/keywords_suggestions/` but it is sending to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/information/?query=web` (the jquery autocomplete feature is implemented on this page `http://127.0.0.1:8000/information/`)

**UPDATE-1**

I've checked /keywords_suggestions/ page in the browser, it shows the **Django server code didn't return the HttpResponse**. Is this the source of a problem? I couldn't understand, the request url from autocomplete itself is not correct. So how could this Django server code cause a problem?

Could anyone tell me the mistake I've done? Thanks!

Comment: shouldn't the dataType be "jsonp"? not that it'll fix your problem, but you might want to change that if you're looking for jsonp

Comment: @ianpgall I tried, but still not working :(

Comment: Your ajax request doesn't actually do anything..  You need a `success` call or something.

Comment: Have you tried making the url `url: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/keywords_suggestions/"`

Comment: Does it request the correct url if you specify an absolute rather than relative url for the .ajax() method?

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#add-keywords").autocomplete({
    source: function( request, response ) {
        var q = $("#add-keywords").val();
        $.ajax({
            url: "/keywords_suggestions/",
            dataType: "json",
            data: {
                    query: q
            },
            success: function(data) {
                // do something here with the returned data
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
    },
    minLength: 2,
    select: function( event, ui ) {
            log( ui.item ?
                "Selected: " + ui.item.label :
                "Nothing selected, input was " + this.value);
    }
});
```

As mentioned above, you need to define a "success" callback function in the data object that you pass into the $.ajax call which tells jQuery what to do with the data once it has been returned.

<strike>Of course, you may have to think about restructuring- AJAX requests execute asynchronously by default, which means that as the browser is waiting for the server to return the data from the AJAX call, it will continue to execute the remaining Javascript code.  In this case, calling the "autocomplete" function likely happens BEFORE the data is returned from the server- and that's no good!</strike>

So if I'm not mistaken, you'll have to restructure this JS to:

1.) Bind, say, a "change" event to "#add-keywords"...

2.) ...so that when a user begins typing, the ajax call is executed

3.) Then, upon successful return of that data, do the autocomplete call that you're trying to stuff that ajax call into as it stands now.

I think this will work for you.  Let me know how it goes.

Comment: Also, try stripping those '/'s from that URL in the $.ajax call (just 'keyword_suggestions', not '/keyword_suggestions/'.  Hard to say which URL is valid without more info about what you're doing server-side.

Comment: Yep, looks like you're going to have to fix the server-side code before you work out that ajax call.  If you can get `keyword-suggestions` to work as intended, then you can start to focus on JS.

Comment: This isn't the way to go about it. The original code will work fine as long as you call the `response` callback supplied to the `source` function. There's really no need to restructure the code. Take a look at the JSONP example on the autocomplete demos page.

Comment: Seems I've muddled things up a bit.  Thanks for pointing this out.  OP, please disregard my suggestion to restructure.  Still stands that the server side code needs to be fixed for the original ajax request to work.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like there are two potential problems here:

1. As you've stated, the Ajax request is being sent to /Information/. I suggest you set **url** to 'http://localhost:8000/keywords_suggestions/'. I don't suggest leaving it this way, but just to see if you can get the request sent to the proper location.
2. The Auto Complete plugin sends "*term*=theSearchTerm" as a GET parameter, not *query*. Did you make any changes to the plugin code to look for *query*, instead?

Also, what happens in your /keywords_suggestions/?

Answer (score 0):

Try giving the outgoing data a type and some manually manipulation of that:

```
$("#add-keywords").autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response) {
        var q = $("#add-keywords").val();
        var pString = '{"query":"' + q + '"}';

        $.ajax({
            url: "/keywords_suggestions/",
            dataType: "json",
            data: pString,
            contentType: "application/json",
            success: function(data) {
                response(data);
            }
        });
    },
    minLength: 2,
    select: function(event, ui) {
        log(ui.item ? "Selected: " + 
        ui.item.label : "Nothing selected, input was " + 
         this.value);
    }
});
```

contentType will tell the server what to expect.

Comment: I tried your code, but still it goes to requesting to the same wrong url and thanks for the help!